# use ajax to fetch mysql content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to fetch the results of a database, namely if the username and password exists in order to move on to another page.  I am able to create a new user, but it is not able to fetch an existing user's info to move onto the next page.

This is my ajax request:

```js
var $signinForm = $("#sigin-form");
var $errorMessage = $signinForm.find(".error-message");
//$signinForm.submit(function(event){

//get rid of default behavior (submit form)
//event.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "loginProcess.php",
  data: $signinForm.serialize(),
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    //handle any errors
    if (data.success != true) {
      console.log("error");
    }
    //if successful
    else{
      //show no errors

      //redirect user to content page
      window.location = "page1.php";
    }
  } 
});
```

And this is my php mysqli requests which should work as ive used them before, but it is not fetching the result:

```html
$myDB = new mysqli($url, $username, $password, $dbName);

/* test database connection */
if ($myDB->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $myDB->connect_errno . ") " . $myDB->connect_error;
}

if(!($getUser = $myDB->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?"))) {
echo "Prepare failed: " . $getUser->errno . " " . $getUser->error;
}
if(!($getUser->bind_param("ss", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))) {
echo "bind_param failed: " . $getUser->errno . " " . $getUser->error;     
}
if(!($getUser->execute())) {
echo "Execute failed1: " . $getUser->errno . " " . $getUser->error;
}
if(!($getUser->bind_result($userID))) {
echo "bind_result failed: " . $getUser->errno . " " . $getUser->error;
}

if(!($getUser->fetch())) {
echo "fetch failed: " . $getUser->errno . " " . $getUser->error;
}
$_SESSION['userID'] = $userID;
$getUser->close();
?>
```

Comment: And where are you sending the user data as the answer to the ajax request?

Comment: You're really storing user passwords in plain text?

Comment: not fetch with ajax? or not fetch when you run the php file directly ?

Comment: @Sven- I am binding the result of the mysqli query to $userID and then saving it to $SESSION['userID'] for later use.

Comment: @Mohamed- it's not fetching from the php, i get a "fetch failed" message when I try to fetch it using php.  But I have to use AJAX to determine if the username/password exists in the database

Comment: That is later use inside PHP, not in Javascript.

Comment: correct, it will be used in another php file

Comment: Are you sure the fetch fails, or are there just no rows returned from your query?

Comment: it fails.  i have 'echo "fetch failed' so that i can tell.  There are 2 rows in the database, so i know the query is fine

Comment: @NateDawg87 If that's the case, then what is the full message you're seeing echoed? According to your code, if it has failed, you should see the reason after `fetch failed: `. For reference, `fetch()` will return false-y if the query has returned no rows, not just if there's an error. I'd suggest checking whether the return values is false or null.

Comment: it comes back with "fetch failed: 0 "